# Laravel Artisan Migrate connection refused

Tags: php, laravel-4

My website works, its clearly accessing the database. I can log in and i can create records, etc...

Ive created a new migration, and I'm trying to insert it, but when i run

```
php artisan migrate
```

i get the error

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection Refused
```

My database config has the passwords hidden in the environment so my config looks like this

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => getenv('DB_HOSTNAME'),
        'database'  => getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'username'  => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

my environment variables are loading correctly. What am i missing?

Comment: Create a script to print out those variables, and then use them locally to see if you can connect with them?

Comment: Tried that and i can connect just fine from command line

Comment: OK, next see if the env vars are being correctly reflected in the web environment. Write your own PHP script to do a PDO/mysql connection to show that this is true, and that it can connect. Run this in the web env rather than at the console - you may have a different version of PHP or a different PHP config here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the environment that artisan was seeing was different from the environment i wanted it to see, so it was using the wrong host

```
php artisan migrate --env=production
```